# Invalid type argument / incompatible pointer type C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I know questions of this form have been asked before, but I'm having difficulty finding one that suits my situation.

As someone trying to get used to C, I'm having issues with pointers, specifically Strings. I have a small number of errors that keep cropping up, and I can't wrap my head around what I keep doing wrong.

I'm writing a program that will read username:password key/values and then compare them against given values. For that, I use a userpass struct:

```
typedef struct {
char user[BUF_MAX];
char pass[BUF_MAX];
} userpass;
```

And the following code:

```
char *authThread(char *filename, char *request){

List_t logins;
char user[BUF_MAX];
char pass[BUF_MAX];
char *saveptr = NULL;
char *listptr = NULL;

char *username = strtok_r(request, ":", &saveptr);
char *password = strtok_r(NULL, ":", &saveptr);

char *failCode = malloc(sizeof (char)*BUF_MAX);
sprintf(failCode, "0:%s:0", username);

char *successCode = malloc(sizeof (char)*BUF_MAX);
sprintf(successCode, "1:%s:%s", username, ticketSecret);

if (List_init(&logins)){

  //Retrieve all the user:pass pairs from the auth file
  FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r");
  while(fscanf(fp, "%s:%s", user, pass) != EOF){
    userpass new;
    //PROBLEM LINES BELOW+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    strcpy(new->user, user);
    strcpy(new->pass, pass);
    List_add_tail(&logins, &new);
  }//while
  fclose(fp);

  //See if the username/pass combination provided exists in the auth file
  for (;;){
    userpass *next = NULL;
    //PROBLEM LINE BELOW+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    List_next_node(&logins, &listptr, &next);
    if (next == NULL) break;

    //Match found, return required auth string
    if (strcmp(next->user, username) == 0 && strcmp(next->pass, password) == 0){
      return successCode;
    }//if
  }//for

  return failCode;

}//if
else{
  printf("Error creating auth list\n");
}//else

}//authThread
```

List_t is a linked list implementation. The header of the List_next_node function is this:

```
int List_next_node ( List_t *list, void **context, void **data );
```

I've labelled the two lines where I get an error above. When I try to compile, I get two errors. On the first two lines, I get: `invalid type argument of â->â`.

One the second line, I get: `passing argument 2(3) of âList_next_nodeâ from incompatible pointer type`

I can see that both of these issues are caused by variables not being the correct type, but I can't see how that's possible. In the first case, `new->user` should be a char array, as should `user`.

In the second case, List_next_node accepts three parameters; a pointer to a list, a pointer to a context pointer, and a pointer to a data pointer. As far as I can tell, everything is the type it should be. I can only imagine it's some problem with how Strings (i.e. char arrays) work in C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` is declared locally on the stack.  It is not a pointer so you need to change

```
userpass new;
strcpy(new->user, user);
strcpy(new->pass, pass);
```

to

```
userpass new;
strcpy(new.user, user);
strcpy(new.pass, pass);
```

Depending on the implementation of `List_add_tail` (I can't see it in your question), this may not be the only problem.  `new` goes out of scope after `List_add_tail` returns so, unless adding an item to the list takes a copy, the list will be left with a pointer to memory that is liable to be reused.

If `List_add_tail` doesn't create a copy of the `userpass*` in its second argument, you should change your code to something like

```
userpass* new = malloc(sizeof(*new));
strcpy(new->user, user);
strcpy(new->pass, pass);
List_add_tail(&logins, &new);
```

(Note that in this last example, `new` is a pointer so we have to use the dereference operator `->` to access its members again.)

Comment: it looks like `userpass` is a data type

Comment: @TaylorFlores Yes, it's a typedef for a struct, shown just above the code in the question

Comment: I just haven't seen a datatype used that way before, it looks weird. Isn't this `c++`? Edit: nevermind, the syntax highlighting was confusing me.

Comment: Taylor Flores:  This is C,  Not C++.  Otherwise "new" would be a keyword which could not be declared as a variable.  Generally you should read up on C to understand fully, but in short, a type declared as `struct foo { ...};` would have to be used as `struct foo bar;` to create a variable of the type.  If you do a typedef like this, you can use the typedef like a regular variable.  It's mostly a stylistic choice, as it essentially compiles to the same code.

Comment: @Taywee, I edited my comment. The syntax highlighting was confusing me, that's all. I don't need to read up on `C`

Comment: TaylorFlores:  Yeah, I noticed the highlighting was a little weird as well.  Perhaps SO should implement lazy-style context-sensitive code blocks based on the language tag of the question.

Comment: Thank you-- this worked. I was going off a similar example from some other code, and I didn't notice that the other code involved a _pointer_ to a struct, while mine was the struct itself.

...And as I was writing this comment you answered the question in my brain, which was if using `new` as a straight struct was going to cause issues. This now makes a little more sense to me XP

Comment: @JMcMinn Glad my answer helped.  Note that I've added a second section to it - depending on the implementation of `List_add_tail` you may need to make some further changes.

Answer (score 1):

**Error 1**

You have defined the variable `new` as a userpass structure yet you access its internal attributes like a pointer.

```
userpass new;
...
strcpy(new->user, user); // new->user is equivalent to (*new).user
strcpy(new->pass, pass);
```

Instead, use the `.` operator:

```
strcpy(new.user, user);
strcpy(new.pass, pass);
```

You should dynamically allocate your userpass structures so that they do not go out of scope.

**Error 2** (It's a warning)

Your argument `&listptr` is of type `char **` yet the function is expecting `void **`. You can cast the argument to remove the warning:

```
 List_next_node(&logins, (void **) &listptr, (void **) &next);
```

Similarly, `&next` is `userpass **` and it is expecting `void **`

Comment: Thanks for the answer! This covers something that simonc's doesn't-- the casting to void**-- but unfortunately I can only accept one response XP Perhaps they should be edited together.